# Props doesn't update correctly with redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-props

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

export function deleteShareholder(shareholder) {
    return {
        type: 'DELETE_SHAREHOLDER',
      payload: shareholder
   }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

case 'DELETE_SHAREHOLDER':
    state = state.shareholdersList.filter(sh => sh.id !== action.payload)
  break
```

I use an array of objects with react and redux, when I delete an object from the array, the array becomes undefined in the current component, but in the parent component, it updates correctly. Yet it is the same props.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>


import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

import ShareholdersList from './shareholdersList'

class SasShareholdersForm extends Component {

 render() {  
  console.log(this.props.shareholders.shareholdersList)
  return(
            <ShareholdersList shareholders={ this.props.shareholders } deleteShareholder={ this.props.deleteShareholder} />
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
 return {
  shareholders: state.shareholders,
 }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
 return {
  deleteShareholder: (shareholderId) => {
   dispatch(deleteShareholder(shareholderId))
  }
 }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps) (SasShareholdersForm)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

import React from 'react'

const ShareholdersList = (props) => {
console.log(props.shareholders.shareholdersList)
 
return (
    <div className="column justify-content-around my-5">
        {props.shareholders && props.shareholders.shareholdersList.map((sh, i) =>
            <div className="py-2" key={i}>
                <div className="form-group row justify-content-between align-items-center mr-2">
                    <button className='btn btn-outline-info mr-2'>Edit</button>
                    <button className='btn btn-outline-danger' onClick={ () => props.deleteShareholder(sh.id) } >{sh.id} X</button>
                </div>
                
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label htmlFor="shCAddress">Adresse:</label>
                    <h6 id="shCAddress" >{sh.shCAddress}</h6>      
                </div>

                <div className="form-row">
                    <div className="form-group col-md-4">
                        <label htmlFor="shCZipcode">Code postal:</label>
                        <h6 id="shCZipcode" >{sh.shCZipcode}</h6>             
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label htmlFor="shCCompanyName">Ville:</label>
                        <h6 id="shCCity" >{sh.shCCity}</h6>             
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
    </div>
)
}
```

Comment: Example code? A better explanation of what you have done so far maybe?

Comment: Please show a [mcve]. Your current code example is missing redux action creators and reducers.

Comment: It's complete now. Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we don't see your whole code, only we can guess and make some suggestions. Please, if people ask for some code, provide the related parts as much as possible. So, it is not complete actually. We can't see your state shape here for example.

Your `DELETE_SHAREHOLDER` case is so wrong. Do not set your state anything like that, do not mutate your state. Probably you want to do something like that:

```
case 'DELETE_SHAREHOLDER': {
    return {
        ...state,
        shareholdersList: [ ...state.shareholdersList.filter(sh => sh.id !== action.payload) ]
    }
}
```